Which type of olive oil is most suitable for my cooking?
I’ve recently been doing a lot of frying and am trying to avoid using products which contain chemicals.
Initially I started using extra virgin olive oil but this is very expensive.  I also understand it’s extracted without heat or chemicals.  This would make if free of chemicals but I’m going to be heating it anyway so I guess buying evoo is a waste it sounds like it’s more for salad dressings.
Seeing that my main goal is to avoid chemicals without much concern for taste, what grade of olive oil should I be getting or/and how can I know it’s free of chemicals added during processing?
Also if I decide not to use olive oil but an alternative oil, which ones are likely not to have added chemicals or once again, how can I know there are no chemicals added during processing?
Thanks.

“…to avoid products which contain chemicals…”  Under most reasonable definitions, all foodstuffs contain chemicals, regardless of how they're extracted or processed.  (Olive oil, for example, already contains oleic acid, linoleic acid, palmitic acid, stearic acid, other triacylglycerols, free fatty acids, sterols, tocopherols, vanillin, tyrosol, pinoresinol, chlorophylls, carotenoids, polyphenols, lutein, lignans, flavonoids…)  — However, wanting no additives is perfectly reasonable (and potentially answerable).

@gidds I did mention “chemicals added during processing”.

What do you consider a chemical, though?  Added aqueous ethanoic acid?  Sodium chloride?  Dihydrogen monoxide (DHMO)?

Labeling depends on region. But in the United States, the USDA publishes a standards defining exactly what various grades of olive oil may contain. The first section has what you are looking for:

§52.1531
Product description.
(a) Olive oil is the oil obtained solely from the fruit of the olive tree (Olea europaea L.), to the exclusion of oils obtained using solvents or re-esterification processes and of any mixture with oils of other kinds and shall meet the minimum requirements of Table I, found in §52.1539 of these grade standards.
(b) Virgin olive oils are the oils obtained from the fruit of the olive tree solely by mechanical or other physical means under conditions, including thermal conditions, that do not lead to alterations in the oil, and which have not undergone any treatment other than washing, decantation, centrifugation, and filtration and shall meet the minimum requirements of Table I, found in §52.1539 of these grade standards. No additives of any kind are permitted.
(c) Olive-pomace oil is the oil obtained by treating olive pomace (the product remaining after the mechanical extraction of olive oil) with solvents or other physical treatments, to the exclusion of oils obtained by synthetic processes and mixture with oils of other kinds and shall meet the minimum requirements of Table I, found in §52.1539 of these grade standards. Alpha-tocopherol is permitted to restore natural tocopherol lost in the refining process for refined olive pomace and olive-pomace oil. Maximum level: 200 mg/kg of total alpha-tocopherol is permitted in the final product.

In summary, products labeled as virgin olive oil or extra-virgin olive oil should meet your standards. Other products, including those simply labeled olive oil, may not.
